# Angular 1/2 hybrid app error in ie9: "TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'ref': object is null or undefined"

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular, internet-explorer-9

I have an Angular 1->2 hybrid app with Angular 1.5.8 and Angular 2.2. I have to support IE9 :(

I have included the core-js shims:

```
<script src="node_modules/core-js/client/shim.min.js"></script>
```

My login page is an Angular 1 form with and Angular 2 footer. All of the Angular 2 footer functionality works just fine, but clicking on or typing into the Angular 1 form elements produces the following error on each event:

```
TypeError: Unable to get value of the property 'ref': object is null or undefined
```

It looks like it has something to do with events, but the ie9 console is next to worthless. Does anyone have an idea what might be causing this, or ideas on how to chase down the cause of this error?

What other information can I provide that might be helpful here?

**Edit**
Things I've tried:

- Setting Typsescript target to es3. No dice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [this shim](https://github.com/narainsagar/angular2-ie9-shims/blob/master/shims_for_IE%402.1.2.js) instead of core-js. core-js has some IE9 issues.

Comment: That worked! I narrowed it down to the polyfill for requestAnimationFrame that was causing this. I've got an issue open if anyone wants to follow along at home: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13917